# Empty data and null status in axios return

Tags: axios, nativescript-vue

I made an app using nativescript-vue and axios. I am using android emulator from android studio.
So my app was working last week because we did this checking. Now I want to make updates to this app but when I try to login, it returns empty `result.data` and null `result.status`

I've tried checking it in Postman to see if maybe the error is in the api but its working properly:
[image]

I also consoled the user login details:

[image]

Here's the consoled axios result:

[image]

here's my method:

[image]

Any help to maybe point me to the right direction is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: were you able to resolve this? almost 1 year later and I run into the same problem

Comment: The theme Ada is using is - SynthWave '84

Answer (score 0):

if you are awaiting the axios call then use this syntax:

```
const response = await axios.post({ method:POST, url:'someUrl',data:'somedata' }, newPost);
```

and then log the response variable to see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue as well, adding

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

To my `AndroidManifest.xml` solved the issue.

```
 <application
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:name="com.tns.NativeScriptApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
....
<application>
```

Comment: I already have that in my `AndroidManifest.xml` but still no luck :( thanks anyways!